# How to set up reverse DNS lookups with on-premises network?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-vpc

I have an AWS VPC with a VPN Gateway connecting to my on-premises network, and a Route53 Resolver rule that forwards all "companyname.net" domains to our on-premises DNS nameserver. With that I'm able to do forward DNS lookups, but I am unable to correctly resolve reverse DNS lookups from my VPC.

For instance, `nslookup my-machine.companyname.net` will successfully resolve to `10.8.190.18`, but from my VPC `nslookup 10.8.190.18` will resolve to `ip-10-8-190-18.ec2.internal`, whereas I'd like it to return `my-machine.companyname.net`.

What I'd like to have is the ability to conditionally use AmazonProvidedDNS for all DNS lookups within my VPC, and my on-premises nameserver for all else. I've struggled to find the right documentation on how to properly set this up. I've also looked at specifying custom nameservers in my DHCP Option Set, but it looks like replacing the `AmazonProvidedDNS` with the on-premises nameserver may have adverse effects on EMR and other services.

Thanks!

Comment: [You have to configure the right reverse dns for 10.8.190.18 so that it shows my-machine.companyname.net instead of ip-10-8-190-18.ec2.internal. What you have now is simple the default form of it.](https://serverfault.com/questions/889637/how-to-set-reverse-dns-in-aws-for-my-private-nameserver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by writing some rules on Route53 Resolver. I created a FORWARD rule for 10.in-addr.arpa to my company's nameserver, and created a SYSTEM rule for my VPC subnet 190.8.10.in-addr.arpa.